# If torque is not observer dependent for bodies in translational equilibrium then why doesn't the angular acceleration change?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

I know that if a body is translational equilibrium then torque about any point is zero and have also understood it's proof. My teacher had told me that angular acceleration about any point will be same provided the point is not a moving point located out of the body. But the moment of inertia about different points are different then how can the angular acceleration and torque be same?

Answer (score 1):

For a rigid both the angular acceleration is the same about any point fixed in the body.  The torque and moment of inertia are not the same about any point, but depend on the point selected.

For translational equilibrium there is no translational acceleration and no rotation and the total torque from all forces is zero regardless of point selected; this is not the general case.

See https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/mechanical-systems/mm-dam/documents/Notes/Dynamics_LectureNotes.pdf for details.

Comment: But if moment of inertia changes and angular acceleration doesn't then how does torque remain constant?(in case of translational equilibrium)

Comment: By the way, how can I get the access to these notes for other chapters. I searched for the link after removing "dynamics lecture notes pdf" part and got access denied

Comment: The link I gave you works for me for the entire book.  Search the web for "Kochmann dynamics".

Comment: In general, torque does not remain constant; torque and the moment of inertia change depending on point selected.  For translational equilibrium there is no translational acceleration and no rotation and the total torque from all forces is zero regardless of point selected; this is not the general case.